# How to print the full progress of disk scans in Python using "badblocks" in Linux Debian?

Tags: python, subprocess, popen, progress, flush

I have a problem with getting complete information with the disk scan progress. I would like to get such answers:

```
LINE: Checking blocks 0 to 41983
LINE: Checking for bad blocks (read-only test): 
LINE: 0.00% done, 0:00 elapsed. (0/0/0 errors)
LINE: 20.04% done, 0:01 elapsed. (0/0/0 errors)
LINE: 40.23% done, 0:02 elapsed. (0/0/0 errors)
LINE: 60.49% done, 0:02 elapsed. (0/0/0 errors)
LINE: 80.51% done, 0:02 elapsed. (0/0/0 errors)
LINE: 99.72% done, 0:02 elapsed. (0/0/0 errors)
LINE: done
LINE: Pass completed, 0 bad blocks found. (0/0/0 errors)
```

As a result of my erroneous script, I receive the following answer:

```
LINE: Checking blocks 0 to 41983
LINE: Checking for bad blocks (read-only test): done 0.00% done, 0:00 elapsed. (0/0/0 errors)
LINE: Pass completed, 0 bad blocks found. (0/0/0 errors)
```

This is my code:

```
import subprocess

proc = subprocess.Popen(["badblocks", "-sv", "/dev/sda1"],stderr=subprocess.PIPE,bufsize=0)

while True:
  line = proc.stderr.readline()

  if line != '':
    print 'LINE: ' + line.rstrip()

  else:
    print 'Complete!'
    break
```

Comment: have you tried to add stdout=subprocess.PIPE ?

Comment: And you should try the script with the communicate method.